# Sorting 2D array in c++

Tags: c++

I saw previous questions with this title but what I’m trying to accomplish is a little different.

I have a 2D array[10][6] that each raw holds data for a specific Day of the month numbered from 1-31 which is held in the first slot, for example, array[0][0], array[1][0].

The days are inserted in a random order and I’m trying to sort the entire raw, where the ‘first number’ represent the day of the month and the ‘x, y or z’ represent some data, for example:

2 y y y y y

3 z z z z z

1 x x x x x

Is it possible to use any standard library sorting that could sort it to be

1 x x x x x

2 y y y y y

3 z z z z z

Thank you.

Comment: You can use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on plain arrays. If the default sorting doesn't give the result you want, you can write a custom `Compare` function/functor and provide it to `std::sort` to be invoked as needed.

Comment: Arrays are not copyable, you can't write `a = b`, if `a` and `b` are arrays. Because of this the standard algorithms don't work when the elements they have to work with are arrays. But your approach requires copying arrays so the standard algorithms aren't going to help you. As is said below, you'd be much better off writing a class to represent each row of data.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're getting tunnel-visioned by your current code that you're not seeing the much better approach: refactor your code into objects.

```
struct Data {
    int day_of_month;
    int num_of_transactions;
    int id;
    int secret_key;
    int last_digit_of_pi;
    int some_other_data;
};

int main() {
    Data arr[10];
    //Load the array with data
    ...
    //Load the array with data

    std::sort(
        std::begin(arr), 
        std::end(arr), 
        [](Data const& d1, Data const& d2) {return d1.day_of_month < d2.day_of_month;}
    );

    //Data is now sorted exactly as you expect
}
```

This solution will occupy the same amount of memory (on most platforms, don't @ me), is easier to understand, and if you decide to refactor the data, like by adding or removing a field, this code will work without needing to modify the array itself.

If you're doing this for a school project and you aren't allowed to write classes yet, then drop the course and find a better teacher/course.

Comment: Just for clarifications. So if each array will hold a row of data, why is the array size 10 and not size 5? Also, in my program I don't know how many rows I will eventually have since it depends about the user input, but cannot be over 30. So do i need to create 30 objects? Thanks

Comment: The example you supplied seemed to imply that you needed an array of 10 objects, each holding 6 values. If you need to handle a variable number of rows, then you should use `std::vector<Data>` instead, using `vector.push_back(Data(...));` to add rows, `std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), ...);` to sort the rows (using the same lambda as before), and `vector[i]` to access individual rows. [Learn more here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: So will an instances of the objects d1- dn will be created on its own?

Comment: @ShaunPeretz That's what `push_back` does: it increases the size of the array, reallocates the array (if it needs to) and then appends the element being added to the end of the array.